# Apache Impala reports "missing disk id" inside query profile

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, impala, mapr

When I launch any query on impala, I get the following message in the profile

`WARNING: The following tables have scan ranges with missing disk id information.`

I executed "compute stats" statement on tables but the warning is still present.

Since I'm using **Apache Impala on MaprFS**, could this warning be related to **HDFS Short-Circuit** (not present on Maprfs)?

Impala version: 2.10 
Mapr-Core version: 6.1.0

Thanks